# Looking for repeater type functionality in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am used to using a Repeater control in conventional ASP.Net web projects. I see ASP.Net MVC doesn't have this sort of thing. What should I be using here?

EDIT:

In response to the question, what am I trying to do that I can't achieve in the foreach. I guess I am trying to get a alternating row style. Also, it just feels somewhat wrong to have stuff other than markup in the view. But maybe I will get over that as I work with it. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest thing to use is a `foreach` loop.
What are you trying to do?

**EDIT**:

```
<%  bool odd = false;
    foreach(var row in something) { %>
    <tr class="<%= odd ? "OddRow" : "EvenRow" %>">
        ...
    </tr>
<% odd = !odd; } %>
```

Comment: +1 My thoughts exactly. There are no controls like we had in non MVC.

Comment: I miss the alternate item template the most i guess.

Comment: You can flip a boolean and use the ternary operator inline, which is actually much easier than duplicating the entire template.

Comment: I always used this technique even in repeaters (using Container.ItemIndex % 2). A much more elegant solution than copy / pasting code into an alternating template IMO.

Answer (score 1):

To add to SLaks response.

You could encapsulate your html into a Partial View.

Call `<%= Html.Partial("ViewName", optional_ViewModel) %>`.

This might feel closer to the repeater control. Where the PartialView would be sort of like your item template.

This approach also lends itself to code reuse very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you miss a lot of the features of WebForms, maybe you just need a richer view engine?  Might I suggest the [Spark View Engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/)?  Like WebForms, there's lots of functionality included so you don't have to keep rewriting the same stuff and/or write a bunch of your own helpers.

Comment: The Spark ViewEngine is very powerful and I definitely like it better than the tag-soup that generally is produced when working with the WebForms ViewEngine...

Answer (score 0):

alternating row style can be achieved by css styles ... 
BTW - each one funcionality from web forms can be achieved in mvc ... in the end all is html, js and css

Answer (score 0):

You could even create an HTML helper for this.